# best approach to hook function

Tags: c++, function-hooking, dll-injection

I have found 2 source code example to hook a function.

Example1:

```
#include "detours.h"
#include "sigscan.h"

// this is the function that the program
// will jump to when sum() is called in the original program (testprogram.exe)

DWORD AddressOfSum = 0;
// template for the original function
typedef int(*sum)(int x, int y); 

int HookSum(int x, int y)
{
    // manipulate the arguments
    x += 500;
    y += 500;

    // we manipulate the arguments here and then
    // redirect the program to the original function

    std::cout << "your program has been hacked! " << std::endl;
    sum originalSum = (sum)AddressOfSum;
    return originalSum(x, y);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    // store the address of sum() in testprogram.exe here.

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        // We will use signature scanning to find the function that we want to hook
        // we will find the function in IDA pro and create a signature from it:

        SigScan Scanner;

        // testprogram.exe is the name of the main module in our target process
        AddressOfSum = Scanner.FindPattern("testprogram.exe", "\x55\x8B\xEC\x8B\x45\x08\x03\x45\x0C", "xxxxxxxxx");

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        // this will hook the function
        DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfSum, &HookSum);

        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        // unhook
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        // this will hook the function
        DetourDetach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfSum, &HookSum);

        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Example2:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include <iostream>
 
#define ADDRESS 0x40133C    //This is the address where our targeted function begins
double (__cdecl* originalFunction)(double); //Pointer to the function we are going to hook, must be declared same as original(returns double and takes double as argument)
 
 
 
/*Our modified function code that is going to be executed
before continuing to the code of original function*/
double hookedFunction(double a)  
{                                 
std::cout << "original function: argument = "<< a << std::endl; //we can access arguments passed to original function
a=50.1337;                                                        //Modify arguments
return originalFunction(a);                                        //before returning to normal execution of function
}
 
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
switch (dwReason)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
originalFunction = (double(__cdecl*)(double))DetourFunction((PBYTE)ADDRESS, (PBYTE)hookedFunction); //Magic
break;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

And I ask what is best easy and flexible approach to hook functions.

My consideration:

1. Example 1: is tested and worked.
2. Example 1: is a filename dependent "testprogram.exe". So if I change the exe file name I need to change the source code.
3. Example 1: "\x55\x8B\xEC\x8B\x45\x08\x03\x45\x0C" this is the address point format and it is not easy to decode like example 2: "0x40133C" (more easy)
4. Example 2: don't work because "detourFunction" is deprecated. Now there is "detourAttach" but I don't known how migrate to it in this case.
5. Example 2: is more easy but old. I don't known if will work in the future (32 or 64 bit)...

Can you help me please to take a decision or suggest me a better/easier solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is much better in my opinion:

- It doesn't use deprecated function, that is probably kept only in the `Detours` library for backward compatibility
- It uses pattern scanning, this is much better then embedding raw address, because lets say you are going to inject the .dll to a game, even if it's old singleplayer game it may have a lot of revisions, so the raw address may point to another function, while the pattern will mostly likely find a match anyway (providing the revisions don't differ too much)

The argument with hardcoded "testprogram.exe" doesn't really matter, beacuse there are a lot of ways to get name of the executable, for example you may use the winapi function [GetModuleFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)

Not sure if I understand correctly the question about migration, however if you wan't to use DetourAttach in the second example there is no problem with that, just call the `DetourAttach` like in first example, but with `ADDRESS` instead of `AddressOfSum` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you, The address that the function to hook start is: ".text:00401670"  I have not undestand how is converted it this to "\x55\x8B\xEC\x8B\x45\x08\x03\x45\x0C". I ask if exist a conversion tool.

Comment: This is pattern. Look at the bytes at 401670 in your executable, the opcodes are translated into assembler instructions by your disassembler, eg /x55/x8B/xEC is translated to "push ebp, mov ebp, esp", so this is standard function prolog.

Comment: you have right, probably it is my fault but the numbers are not exact the some: 

file code: 55 8B EC 6A 0A 8B 45 08 8B 55 08 03 51 04
address: 55 8B EC 8B 45 08 03 45

it is normal ?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct address? In the question you have posted `0x40133C`, not `0x401670`

Comment: 0x40133C is the old project. 0x401670 is the address that IDA show me at the start of the function hook. In this case is "main". Now I update my question with other screenshots.

Comment: How did you generate the pattern then? It looks like your code is hooking another function than you think.

Comment: you must excuse me again. I have found the wrong function due too difficount find it in assembly. The correct address is 00401090 and match exactly with code in asembly. many many thanks again !!!